# Remove future posts from VuePress

Tags: vuepress

How can I completely remove future posts from VuePress?

I want to have posts with future date in my blog run by VuePress and only reveal them once their publish date has come. This kind of works, as the post does not come up anywhere on the site, but if I enter its exact URL, I can still see and read it.

It seems that when I enter an URL of a future post, I get to the 404 page, and then get redirected to the post.

I'm using [VuePress Plugin Janitor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuepress-plugin-janitor) which removes the files of future blog posts, but this is not enough. I've also tried using [Dehydrate](https://vuepress.github.io/en/plugins/dehydrate/) plugin, but neither seem to fix the issue I'm having.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else finds themselves in the same situation. It seems I was using the Dehydrate plugin incorrectly.

```js
// .vuepress/config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    'vuepress-plugin-dehydrate',
    {
      noSSR: [], // leave noSSR empty
      noScript: [
        '404.html' // add 404 to noScript.
                   // My mistake was adding 404 to both, noSSR and noScript
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```